# AudioSystem.write(input, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, file) produces a corrupt WAVE file. Invalid RIFF length

Tags: java, audio, wav

This code is producing WAV files that don't work in many apps.

When I check in a RIFFVIEWER app it complains about invalid RIFF length. BWFMetaEdit claims the file is truncated. Some tolerant apps like Audacity will play them.

Am I doing something wrong here or is java audio buggy?

```
// The essence data is PCM formatted, so convert it to a WAVE file
File extractPCM(WAVEPCMDescriptor descriptor, EssenceData data, String name) {
    try {
        Stream stream = data.getEssenceStream();
        URI uri = stream.getStreamURI();
        int hashCode = uri.hashCode();

        File file = new File(mediaDir, 
                name + "_" +
                String.format("%08X", hashCode)
                + ".wav"
                );

        if (file.exists()) {
            return file;
        }

        mediaDir.mkdir(); // Ensure exists

        log("Copying essence data stream"); 

        stream.setPosition(0);
        ByteBuffer buff = stream.read((int)stream.getLength());
        stream.close();
        buff.flip();

        AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(
                Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
                (float)descriptor.getSampleRate().doubleValue(),
                (int)descriptor.getQuantizationBits(),
                (int)descriptor.getChannelCount(),
                (int)descriptor.getBlockAlign(),
                (float)descriptor.getAverageBytesPerSecond(),
                false
                );
        AudioInputStream input = new AudioInputStream(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(buff.array()), format, buff.capacity());           
        AudioSystem.write(input,
                   AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, file);        
        log("Extracted file " + file);
        return file;
    } catch (EndOfDataException | IllegalArgumentException | IOException e1) {
        log(e1);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I was supplying the length as bytes instead of sample frames.

When I divide the buffer size by the frame size, non tolerant apps stop complaining.

```
AudioInputStream input = new AudioInputStream(
        new ByteArrayInputStream(buff.array()), format, buff.capacity() / format.getFrameSize());
```

Comment: However this is not the end of it. AudioSystem.write still produces a WAV that is not spec compliant. It violates the padding requirement in a RIFF WAV file. So some app still complain. Most now will play it though.